# change root view controller with Side menu

Tags: ios, swift, side-menu

I'm trying to change RootViewController with another ViewController. But I can't figure it out. I'm facing some problems that are

After changed rootViewController by above code then new viewController is disappear.
In console log : Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged .
Please help me!

My code is :

```
func changeRootView(){
guard let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate else {
    return
}
guard let window = (delegate as! AppDelegate).window else {
    return
}
UIView.transition(with: window, duration: 0.3, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
    let lgv = DriverMainViewController()
    window.rootViewController = UINavigationViewController(rootViewController: lgv)
}, completion: { completed in
    SideMenuManager.menuLeftNavigationController!.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    print ("changed")
})
```

}

[Picture before change RootviewController
When I clicked that gray button then changeRootView function will run.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3fhI.jpg)

[Then changeRootView function changed App keyWindow's rootViewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eou5.jpg)

But this blue backgrounded viewController is disappeared in 1 second.
This screen shot is after disappeared new root view controller.

Answer (score 1):

I think what is happening here is that when you set the `rootViewController` of the window, the old `rootViewController` is no longer referenced and it gets deleted by ARC.  What you might try is capturing the out-going view controller so that it sticks around for the duration of the animation.  Try this:

```
func changeRootView(){
    guard let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate else { return }
    guard let window = (delegate as! AppDelegate).window else { return }

    // capture a reference to the old root controller so it doesn't
    // go away until the animation completes
    let oldRootController = window.rootViewController

    UIView.transition(with: window, 
                  duration: 0.3, 
                   options: .transitionCrossDissolve, 
                animations: {
                    let lgv = DriverMainViewController()
                    window.rootViewController = UINavigationViewController(rootViewController: lgv)
                }, 
                completion: { completed in

                    // OK, we're done with the old root controller now
                    oldRootController = nil

                    SideMenuManager.menuLeftNavigationController!.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                    print ("changed")
                }
    )
}
```

What this code is doing is adding a reference to the window's existing root view controller and then capturing it in the completion block to control how long it exists.